# php float math operation bug?

Tags: php, floating-accuracy

the summary here:

```
$a = 213480.7-190.46;
exit($a-213290.24);
# 2.9103830456734E-11
```

the result output suppose to be 0. but it output

the story of the operation result :

```
$b is : 213480.7
-190.46
$b is : 213290.24
```

now the balance looks correct. but when use comparison operator.. the result is weird
here is the var_dump and compare result

```
var_dump($b);
# float 213290.24

if ($b==213290.24) {
    exit('same');
} elseif ($b>213290.24) {
    exit('larger '.($b-213290.24));
} else {
    exit('smaller '.($b-213290.24));
}
#larger 2.9103830456734E-11
```

can anyone tell me how to solve it??

Comment: vote down? i dont understand? is my problem??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you already tagged your question with the answer: floating-accuracy.

Comment: thanks for identify the problem for me. no solution?

Comment: That depends on what your goal is with this. Allowing some diversion is the usual thing to do (`abs(123.456 - $a) < 0.002`), but it may not be what you want.

Comment: ok. then i'll try alternative solution. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and never
>   compare floating point numbers for equality. If higher precision is
>   necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions
>   are available.

The common method of dealing with float comparisons is to add an allowable epsilon, or small difference in floating point values, so anything within a small tolerance is considered equivalent.

```
if (abs(213290.24 - $b) < .001) {
    exit('same')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Computations performed on floating point numeric values always have [inherent error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980) resulting from their machine representation. For this reason, you should not use the equality operator `==` to compare floating point values.

The typical approach is to decide on a minimum allowable error, and check if the difference between the values you want to compare is less than the desired error.

```
$min_error = 0.00001;
if (abs($a - $b) < $min_error) 
{
   exit("same");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not problem of php, it's connected with the nature of binary float.
You can't represent all rational number accurately with float. For example, you might try to compare 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3, it will be failse, because 0.3 is not represented accurately.